# Using REST to filter Share Point date field

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I need to filter the date in wish an item was received in a SharePoint list using REST. I have it partially working, but I have a problem. I'm using a Datepicker to select the date I'm using as filter, but when the date is picked and converted to an acceptable format using `toISOString()`, I get an "exact" date (e.g. `2018-06-15T00:00:00.000Z`). The issue with that is that the Date portion (`2018-06-15`) matches OK, but not the Time portion, because the datepicker will always give a different time (HH:MM:SS) than the SharePoint list entry.

This is what I'm using:

```
... $filter=Date_Received eq datetime'2018-05-11T04:00:00.000Z'
```

I have several items that were entered on 6/15/2018, but I get no values, because the time they were entered was different (e.g. 2018-06-15T05:00:00Z). Is there a way to use something like `substringof` to filter dates, or does anyone has a workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates in SharePoint are stored in GMT. So the times recorded are London times.

**Option 1** - Use ranges:

```
$filter=Date_Received gt datetime'2018-05-10T20:00:00.000Z' and Date_Received lt datetime'2018-05-11T20:00:00.000Z'
```

If you are not looking for files near midnight then:

```
$filter=Date_Received gt datetime'2018-05-11T00:00:00.000Z' and Date_Received lt datetime'2018-05-11T23:59:59.000Z'
```

**Option 2** - Use the SharePoint 2010 REST API and date functions:

```
/sites/yourSite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/yourList?$filter=year(Date_Received) eq 2018 and month(Date_Received) eq 5 and day(Date_Received) eq 11
```

This still has an issue for dates around midnight due to GMT.

**Option 3** - Use SharePoint 2010 REST API with a calculated column:

Add a Calculated column named Date_Received_Text as: =TEXT(Date_Received,"yyyy-mm-dd")

```
/sites/yourSite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/yourList?$filter=Date_Received_Text eq '2018-07-08'
```

Same midnight issue...

Note: The 2010 API still works in SharePoint Online.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out a couple of days ago an option very similar to what you proposed on Option 1. I just replaced everything after the 'T' with 00:00:00 and 11:59:59, used ranges, and it worked, but I may also use other of your options, specially using 'Year'.